# Create function not existing in class with NetBeans PHP

Tags: php, ide, netbeans

i have seen a lot of screencasts where the author is creating methods with the following way:

```
$myObj = new myObj();
$myObj->getAllMyWhatEver($xyz);
```

The "getAllMyWhatEver" function is not existing yet, he is clicking some kind of key and the function is created in the proper class.

Does someone knows how to do this in Netbeans??

Comment: Don't they tell you in the screencasts?

Comment: It would be very annoying if you use `\_\_call()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select the method and `Alt+Enter` will give you a list of choices where you can create the method in the corresponding class, surround the selection with //...

or on the left side of your line, you should have a light bulb. Click on it and it will give you the same choices as above.

Answer (score 1):

[Netbeans: Top 10 Netbeans Shortcuts](http://netbeanside61.blogspot.com/2008/04/top-10-netbeans-ide-keyboard-shortcuts.html), try alt + insert ( Generate Code )